# Adding Button to add points to another sheet - Basketball Live Scorebook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have created a scorebook sheet in google sheet for tracking live basketball stats.
One sheet with the scorebook table for the team with each player one a row.

I want to have a separate tab for data entry that populates the scorebook table.
This entry sheet will list the 5 players on the floor (column A will have jersey numbers which can change when players subs in)
I want to have a series of buttons to add 2pts/3pts/fouls/etc. to the player listed in column A to the appropriate row on the scorebook table.

We have an app that does this beautifully, but it requires downloading a csv file to get the table data. I want to create a similar experience with a google sheet that fills in real-time.

My thought was to create buttons for each change. I have enough formula knowledge to know how to create a vlookup formula to look at column A and the row to find the player. But I need to make this a clickable button to change the data on the fly.

Any suggestion would be helpful.